# What's special ammo in Destiny 2?

Tags: destiny-2

In Destiny 2, I frequently come across weapons that require 'special ammo' of which I either don't have, or the game never drops.

How do I get hold of these? And is it worth it?

I'm already having quite a good time with the available arsenal as it is, but I  would also like to know about these.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Destiny 2, special ammo weapons use a different type of ammo due to their higher damage or specialized use. Special ammo weapons include:

- Shotguns
- Snipers
- Fusion and Linear Fusion Rifles (Arbalest, Lorentz Driver)
- Breech-loaded Grenade Launchers
- Trace Rifles
- Glaives

Exceptions to this list are as follows:

- Eriana's Vow (Hand cannon, solar)
- Forerunner (Sidearm, kinetic slot)

Special ammo appears as green ammo bricks when killing enemies, but will only drop if you currently have a weapon that requires special ammo equipped. When starting a new activity (such as a story mission or a strike) the game will make sure you start with a small amount of special ammo if you have one of these weapons equipped. If, however, you switch to a special ammo weapon during an activity then you will need to defeat enemies to obtain special ammo.

Special ammo weapons can be worthwhile in PvE due to their higher single-target damage potential, making them useful against tougher enemies. In PvP, special ammo weapons often have the potential to kill opponents with a single shot.

Comment: You're thinking of the difference between Energy and Kinetic weapons. Snipers and Shotguns use Special ammo regardless of damage type.

Comment: You’re right, my mistake

Answer (score 10):

The game will only drop special ammo, if you have a weapon equipped that uses it.

It's also worth mentioning that if you are on a planet, and switch to your special ammo weapon you will always start with 0. But if you for example go to the traveler/the farm first equip the special ammo weapon, then go to a planet you will always start with some.

If it is worth it is all dependent on your gameplay. If you like using snipers then yes because snipers use special ammo.

Also weapons like the [coldheart](https://db.destinytracker.com/d2/ru/items/1345867571-coldheart) and the [prometheus lens](https://db.destinytracker.com/d2/en/items/19024058-prometheus-lens) use special ammo, they are fun to use and very good in pve.

Comment: What do you mean by going to the traveler first? You mean going to farm? I'm a level 12 Hunter.

Comment: @DrFish Looks like you haven't unlocked the Traveler/Last City. It gets unlocked once you beat the main story :)

Comment: @DrFish Oh yes, sorry before the Traveler is the Farm.